# Creating a JMS Correlation ID

Tags: jms

It is generally discouraged to use the message id returned from the JMS provider as the correlation id with which a message is published onto a queue.  How have people generated their correlation ids for a request/response architecture?

Comment: It is?  The spec specifically mentions using the message ID as the correlation ID.  It then says that "in some cases" an application may need to roll your own correlation ID.

Comment: check this link out.
http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=44779

Comment: Ah - so you are dealing with spec non-compliance.  The spec mandates the ability to set this field so if you move MsgID to CorrelID and the value changes, it's not compliant.  In a compliant provider, this would work as intended because the MsgID would be unique, even across message engines, and you could reliably set the CorrelID.   Yeah, you probably need to roll your own.

Comment: Sorry, I have two conflicts. First, I disagree with the premise. I also specialize in IBM's JMS implementation which doesn't have this issue. Having never had to deal with it, I don't have a basis for evaluating solutions, although I'll add a comment to Stu's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Clients can use a unique ID standard like `UUID` to generate a new ID.
[Here](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/total-traceability/) is good tutorial for you.

You can return correlation id from JMS provider using following code.

```
message.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
producer.send(message);
LOG.info("jms-client sent:" + message.getJMSCorrelationID());
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

**Server-side correlation ID generation suffers from two problems though:**

1. One-way protocols (like JMS) have no direct means of returning the
   correlation ID back to the client. Another channel could be used but
   that complicates things.
2. Unexpected issues can prevent the client from receiving the
   generated    ID even though the request has been accepted and
   processed on the    server. This is why client ID generation should
   be considered.

**Client generated correlation IDs**

Clients can use a unique ID standard like UUID to generate a new ID

```
  message.setJMSCorrelationID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

Ref: http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/total-traceability/